# Docker prunes image and networks by itself

Tags: docker

I have a [script](https://framagit.org/Nautigsam/kube-selfhost/-/blob/master/ansible/roles/backup-source/templates/backup_script.j2) which performs backup of several docker volumes during the night.

It starts by stopping the containers that use these volumes, then it creates a new container with all the volumes mounted and back them up with borg. Finally it restarts the containers.

Sometimes the scripts runs into weird issues, like a container can not start because its image or a network it uses is missing. Is it possible that docker daemon prunes them while my backup script is running? How can I disable it?

I could not see anything in daemon logs.

Comment: Please show us the script. Without knowing exactly what you're doing, it's not very possible for us to provide you with an answer.

Comment: I added a link to the script. This is only a jinja2 template but It is enough to understand what the script is doing.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you have the `docker run` command with `--rm` option. In the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up---rm) it says:

> If you set the --rm flag, Docker also removes the anonymous volumes associated with the container when the container is removed. This is similar to running docker rm -v my-container

Perhaps this is why the volumes are being deleted?

Answer (score 0):

No, docker does not automatically prune networks or images. That is left to the user to implement with their own tooling or scripting. It is possible for docker-compose to remove networks, but only when running a `docker-compose down`, and that doesn't remove networks. You'll need to search your own environment to see what you have running that performs a prune.